# have to press the layout first before pressing any item inside

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an android app with a login Activity as the `main-activity`, after launching, and when aiming to press any element in it, nothing happened, but when press it again, it works, I tried to figure out what happening, So, I figured out it's the layout which has to be touched anywhere first before touching any item inside it, also that works for one access only, and to make another one I've to press the layout again, So,it requires from me to make a first layout touch before every element interaction.

**The Activity Layout Structure:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView />

    <LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout>

            <TextView />

            <EditText />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout>

            <TextView />

            <EditText />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button />

        <TextView />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton />

        <ImageButton />

        <ImageButton />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**How I declare the Activity in the** `manifest.xml` **:**

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.example.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: what's your current xml layout and java code?

Comment: @Malvin I really don't know what to post, it's an activity with about 1.5k loc and a several hundred lines on xml , and I can't predict where is the error

Comment: where you are setting your click listener ?

Comment: @Pr38y it's the last thing i do in `onCreate`, which is the declaration on the elements along with the `onClickListeners`

Comment: Any viewgroups/ layouts that contains the element to be clicked? and your click listeners?

Comment: what is your parent layout?

Comment: It's a normal `LinearLayout`

Comment: have you tried descendantFocusability ?

Comment: have you debugged `onClick` event. Its not firing for the first time but on second time?

Comment: @Pr38y yes I tried that, the onClick not even entered in the first time, by the way I added my layout structure above.

Comment: there is nothing in the layout that could take focus before childView. Debug your code to see if the onClickListener has been added or not , when you click for the first time

Comment: @Pr38y the problem isn't on the onClick, as if we suppose that it added after the first touch, it must work then forever but that don't happen as it requires from me to make a first layout touch before every element interaction

Comment: are you setting ontouchlistener on your layout. can you share your click listener code